# Sorting two stacks by using structs - compile error

Tags: c, sorting, stack

There are 3 stacks - A, B, C

Stacks A and B are sorted (the number on the top of the stack is the biggest). Stack C is Empty Only 5 operation are allowed:

push, pop, top, is_empty, create

We need to write a function that receives the stacks A and B, moves all the numbers in stacks A and B to stack C and stack C must be sorted (biggest Number is on top).

I have the algorithm :

Compare top of A with top of B

Pop the least element and push to stack C

Repeat step 2 until any of the stack ( A or B) becomes empty

Move remaining elements from non-empty stack to C. Now you have all the elements in C  but in ascending order. (That is least element at top).

Move all the elements from C to A. (Contents in A are in descending order)

Move all the elements from A to B. (Contents in B are in ascending order)

Move all the elements from B to C.

and i started to write the code but there are errors and i don't know why !

the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX_MEMBERS 8

typedef struct
{
    int x[MAX_MEMBERS];
    int top;
}STACK;

void create_stack(STACK *s)
{
    s->top=-1;
}

int is_empty(STACK *s)
{
return s->top==-1;
}

int is_full(STACK *s)
{
return s->top==MAX_MEMBERS-1;
}

int pop(STACK *s)
{
    return s->x[s->top--];
}

void push(STACK *s,int item)
{
    s->x[++s->top]=item;
}

int top(STACK *s)
{
    return s->x[s->top];
}

void ex1(STACK *a, STACK *b)
{
    STACK c;
    while(!is_empty(a)&&!is_empty(b))
    {
        if(top(&a)>top(&b))

            push(&c,pop(&a));


        else if(top(&a)<top(&b))
        push(&c,pop(&b));

        else
        {
            pop(&a);
            push(&c,pop(&b));
        }
    }
    if(is_empty(&a))
    while(!is_empty(&b))
    push(&c,pop(&b));

    else while(!is_empty(&a))
    push(&c,pop(&a));

    while(!is_empty(&c))
    push(&a,pop(&c));
    while(!is_empty(&a))
    push(&b,pop(&a));
    while(!is_empty(&b))
    push(&c,pop(&b));
}


main()
{
    STACK a,b;
    int i,x;
    create_stack(&a);
    create_stack(&b);
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("enter a num for stack a :\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        push(&a,x);
        printf("enter a num for stack b :\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        push(&b,x);
    }
    ex1(a,b);
}
```

Comment: `C` would be in descending order not ascending order..cuz when you pop `C` it would be in descending order

Comment: sort algorithm is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of errors, many of them come down to the `push` signature:

```
void push(STACK s,int item)
```

which looks like it should be:

```
void push(STACK *s,int item)
```

The rest come down to not passing addresses of `STACK` structs to your functions, for example:

```
push(a,x);
```

should be:

```
push(&a,x);
```

Also `main` should always return `int`:

```
int main()
```